# How do I implement WebWorkers in Angular 7 using TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, data-binding

I have an `Array<any>` in a parent component that is in a parent-child one-way binding to a child component. When the `Array` in the parent component updates (grows/shrink), the child component should register such changes and update accordingly. However, my code is not working.

My parent component's TypeScript looks like the following.

```
export class AppComponent {
 myList: Array<any>;

 constructor() {
  this.myList = new Array<any>();
 }

 buttonClicked() {
  let counter = 0;
  while (counter < 100) {
   //do something very long
   const result = doSomething();
   this.myList.push(result);
   counter += 1;
  }
 }
}
```

And the parent HTML looks like the following.

```
<div>
 <app-child-component [list]="myList">
 </app-child-component>
</div>
```

My child component TypeScript looks like the following.

```
export class ChildComponent {
 @Input('list')
 list: Array<any>;
}
```

My child component HTML looks like the following.

```
<h1>{{list.length}}</h1>
<div *ngFor="let obj of list">
 {{obj.toString()}}
</div>
```

This code setup "works" only in the sense in that after the long-running process in the parent is finished, do I see the binding actually take place. However, I want the binding or changes to take place in the child component as the work and `Array<any>` is being updated/appended to in the parent.

I searched a little bit online, but most of the code samples are for older versions of Angular.

I've mocked the problem [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-srzb3w).

It turns out that the way my code is written, it is blocking the UI. The only thing I can think of doing is using `WebWorker`. However, there is [very little documentation and/or examples](https://angular.io/api/platform-webworker). Additionally, this [article](https://medium.com/@ganeshsurfs/non-blocking-performant-web-worker-in-your-angular-application-808fb9ab98c2) shows how to use WebWorkers in Angular 6 (close to 7), but it seems to imply that my WebWorker file be written in JavaScript. Is there an end-to-end TypeScript Angular 7 approach?

Comment: Make your array operation pure, avoiding to use side effect (push item to array), cause this will make heavily change detecting for angular. After you get your new array, simply assign the new array to `myList`.

Comment: Try using change detection. Inject `ChangeaDetectionRef` in your parent component constructor. And try using `cd.markForCheck()` or `cd.detectChanges()`

Comment: Remember Javascript code execution is synchronous. You are trying to achieve asynchronously update your Child component, in which case you would have to make your Parent Component's worker code async somehow

Comment: @Rikin You are right. When I hit the button to kick off the long-running process, I noticed the button is "locked". Meaning, the whole UI is locked/blocked. This reminds me of the infamous `Event Dispatch Thread` in Java GUI programming. I think one way I've read in the past to do as you are saying is with WebWorkers; but the last time I looked, WebWorkers + Angular integration was an IQ test to understand + implement properly. Any Angular-friendly API/frameworks you know of to ease the pain?

Comment: Easiest way to get started would be to use `setTimeout` and put wrapped execution in backlog. Another way is to use Google's service worker API: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/ Alternatively you can use: https://github.com/developit/greenlet

Comment: Or may be this should help: https://github.com/mchaov/WebWorkers